# Selecciono una fecha de un calendario y recibo un dia menos

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema con la zona horaria. Existen ciertas zonas horarias donde mi app funciona, y ciertas zonas horarias donde no funciona. Entonces noté que al querer construir una fecha, por ejemplo

```
const d = new Date("2023-11-04");
```

El resultado que me muestra la consola es el siguiente

```
Fri Nov 03 2023 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

Encontre un monton de funciones que convierten la fecha y me devuelven el dia correcto (4 de noviembre) pero en formatos diferentes.

Yo quiero recibir el mismo formato. Hay alguna manera de obtener `Sat Nov 04 2023 00:00:00 GMT-00 (timezone correspondiente)` al crear una nueva fecha independientemente de la zona horaria del usuario?

Por ejemplo intente convertirla con `toUTCString` y si bien el resultado se parece mucho a lo que necesito, no me sirve

```js
const d = new Date("2023-11-04");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;


const c = new Date("2023-11-04").toUTCString();
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = c;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

La función Date en JavaScript se utiliza para crear una nueva instancia de un objeto de fecha y hora. Acepta varios formatos de argumentos, y en el ejemplo que proporcionaste, estás usando el formato que toma los valores numéricos para año, mes y día.

El código new Date(2023,10,4); crea una fecha que representa el 4 de noviembre de 2023. Veamos cada uno de los componentes:

**2023** - Es el año de la fecha.

**10** - Es el mes de la fecha. Aquí es donde es un poco confuso para aquellos que son nuevos en JavaScript. Los meses en JavaScript están indexados desde 0, lo que significa que 0 es enero, 1 es febrero, y así sucesivamente. Por lo tanto, 10 representa noviembre.

**4** - Es el día del mes.

Cabe destacar que si solo proporcionas el año y el mes (es decir, omites el día), el día por defecto será el 1 del mes especificado.

También hay que tener en cuenta las zonas horarias. Cuando creas una fecha de esta manera, se crea en la zona horaria local del usuario (del navegador). Si necesitas trabajar con fechas y horas en una zona horaria específica o en formato UTC, tendrás que hacer ajustes adicionales o usar bibliotecas especializadas como moment-timezone.

Al proporcionar una cadena en el formato "YYYY-MM-DD" al constructor Date de JavaScript, estás especificando una fecha en el formato de fecha ISO 8601.

Cuando utilizas el formato "2023-11-04", estás indicando:

**2023**: Año

**11**: Mes (Noviembre)

**04**: Día

Hasta aquí, parece que se comportaría de la misma manera que new Date(2023,10,4), pero hay una diferencia crucial en términos de la zona horaria:

1. Cuando pasas una cadena en el formato ISO 8601 a Date, JavaScript la interpreta como una fecha/hora en el Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). Por lo tanto, new Date("2023-11-04") te dará una fecha que representa el 4 de noviembre de 2023 a las 00:00 horas UTC.
2. Por otro lado, cuando pasas números separados como en new Date(2023,10,4), JavaScript interpreta esos números en la zona horaria local del usuario.

Así que, dependiendo de tu zona horaria, al hacer un console.log de new Date("2023-11-04"), podrías ver algo diferente a medianoche si no estás en la zona horaria UTC.

Por ejemplo, si estás en la zona horaria UTC+3, al imprimir esa fecha, verías:

**2023-11-04T03:00:00.000Z**

Esto se debe a que la fecha es interpretada en UTC y luego se muestra en tu zona horaria local.

Si deseas interpretar la fecha "2023-11-04" en la zona horaria local del usuario, tendrías que descomponer la cadena y pasar los componentes como números al constructor de Date.

Aquí hay una forma de hacerlo:

```js
const dateString = "2023-11-04";
const parts = dateString.split('-');
const year = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
const month = parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1; // Los meses están indexados desde 0.
const day = parseInt(parts[2], 10);

const localDate = new Date(year, month, day);
console.log(localDate);
```

Este código toma la fecha en formato ISO como una cadena, la divide en sus componentes y luego crea un objeto Date en la zona horaria local del usuario utilizando esos componentes.

Recuerda que el mes se reduce en 1 porque en JavaScript, los meses están indexados desde 0 (0 es enero, 1 es febrero, etc.). Por eso, se le resta 1 al mes extraído de la cadena de fecha ISO.

Y para el detalle del formato de fecha puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
const d = new Date("2023-11-04");
console.log(d.toISOString().slice(0,10));
```

Comment: Y esto es la respuesta a???

Comment: Es mas una explicacion al porque ocurre esto cuando se pasa la fecha a javascript usando un String, pero creo me fui de largo con la explicacion y olvide dar la respuesta final a lo que pedia, ahorita le modifico

Answer (score 0):

El tema de las fechas en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) es un lio.

Cuando la creas como `string` y usas `toString` te cambia la hora a local y no respeta la hora ingresada. Esto no pasa si lo creas ingresando los "Números" por partes de Año, Mes, Días, hora, etc.

Por ejemplo:

**1.- Como string:**

```js
const d = new Date("2023-11-04");

console.log(d);
console.log(d.toString());
```

**1.- Como "Número":**

*OJO: El primer mes (Enero) es el mes cero, por lo que Noviembre es el mes 10*

```js
const d = new Date(2023,10,4);
console.log(d);
console.log(d.toString());
```